# Multiple databases in RavenDB

Tags: database, instance, ravendb

We are planning to use RavenDB in a production environment and different customers will have different databases, but I would like to use the same instance of RavenDB.

This page describes the creation of multiple  databases: http://ravendb.net/documentation/multiple-databases

I have tried to create a `Databases`-folder in the server-folder and then created a file named  `MyCustomerName` (without extension). I have tried different other things, but I keep getting the message:

```
{
  "Url": "/databases/MyCustomerName",
  "Message": "Could not find a database named: MyCustomerName",
  "Error": "Could not find a database named: MyCustomerName"
}
```

This page above is the only source I could find on the subject and I'm sure I only need a little direction to make this work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stephan,
the documentation doesn't talk about a "file", it talks about a "document".
You should be creating a *document* inside the master database that describe this.

You can also do this using the API by calling:

```
store.DatabaseCommands.EnsureDatabaseExists(name);
```

Comment: I had trouble finding this method. It's in `Raven.Client.Extensions`.

Comment: FYI: moved to ```store.DatabaseCommands.GlobalAdmin.EnsureDatabaseExists(name);```